# Wired ADSL2 Router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, lan, wireless-access-point

I have an ADSL2 Router and as of now I connect to the Internet with a LAN cable.  I want to access the Internet wirelessly.  How do I do this?  Do I create an access point to this existing router so that I can access the Internet wirelessly?

Comment: What type of router do you have? Does your router support wireless, and does your PC? If your router does not have wireless then you could add an access point to it via lan cable but it might be simpler to just buy a new router that does have wireless.

Comment: How is this programming-related?

Comment: Hi Rup, How do i add an access point to my existing router ?

Comment: Post it in http://www.serverfault.com and check the FAQ of this site - http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: better ask add http://serverfault.com or http://superuser.com

Comment: Oki.. Sorry for posting it here . I thought its something relating to hardware and there was a tag "Hardware" . Hnece the post . Thank you All of you for your time !!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly the make and model of router you have (and assuming it's one with wireless capabilities), it's impossible to provide specific instructions. Basically the way it works is you use a browser to access the router's built-in set-up page through its gateway address (usually something like http://192.168.0.1 or http://192.168.100.0) where you'll enable wireless connections and configure the features you want to use, like WEP or WPA/WPA2 encryption and related password/passphrase, etc.

How to do this is usually described in the manual, which may come in printed form or be on a CD that came with the router. You can probably also find a copy online at the manufacturer's website.